# How can I sign as CA a multi domain certificate

Tags: openssl, certificates

I have set myself up as a Certicate Authority so I can sign certificates I need for development.  I have imported my CA certificate in my browsers so certificates I sign are accepted without question

As NOT the CA, I made myself a Certificate Signing Request containing a Common Name for one internal domain name, and added about 10 other (internal) domain names with the objective of having myself as CA sign it.  The CSR has those names - I can see them when I look at it.

I signed the certificate as CA, using my own openssl.cnf file that I normal use for my single domain certificates and it appears to have stipped out all the AltSubjectNames, so the signed certificate I have produced is only good for the one domain in the CN field.  My browsers complain when I try and use it for one of the other domains.

I think I need to adjust the extension in my CAs openssl.cnf file to not strip them out.  The man page for CA points me at the man page for x509v3_config.  But the reading of this is obscure and I can't figure out what to do.

Searching the internet for solutions came up with nothing - there are plenty of descriptions as to how to get the CSR, but absolutely nothing about how a CA can carry over the AltSubjectNames in the CSR into the final Certificate.

How is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found an answer.

The CA_default section of the CA's openssl.cnf file should contain

`copy_entensions = copy`

Then extensions in the request are copied to the certificate.

It doesn't appear possible to limit this to only subjectAltName entries.

Comment: If you have an extension configured in your CSR and also in the CA's configuration, the CA's will take precedence.  You can use that to limit some values.  Of course, as a CA, you should check all requests before approving them and simply reject those who don't adhere to your policies ;-)